# Extracting JSON database

Tags: json, xml, r

I'm trying to retrieve the data from [this page](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/facilities-leadership), and [this is the specific json file](http://catalog.data.gov/harvest/object/5630b80a-23dc-483f-8164-876dac1a9757) associated with it.

I cant seem to extract any meaningful data about the facilities, and it seems like the json file is just a description with no observations.

I'm trying to import it using R packages. I've tried JSON viewers. The documentation page from the first link seems to be in XML.

Comment: very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this will help you see the structure `jsonlite::fromJSON("http://catalog.data.gov/harvest/object/5630b80a-23dc-483f-8164-876dac1a9757")`

I think you'll need more understanding of the API, and the `R` part will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from that url:

```
library(jsonlite) #install these if need be
library(curl)
my_dat <- fromJSON('http://catalog.data.gov/harvest/object/5630b80a-23dc-483f-8164-876dac1a9757')
```

Now you have a list called `my_dat` with the contents

```
> my_dat
$`@type`
[1] "dcat:Dataset"

$accessLevel
[1] "public"

$bureauCode
[1] "029:40"

$contactPoint
$contactPoint$`@type`
[1] "vcard:Contact"

$contactPoint$fn
[1] "Kevin Reid"

$contactPoint$hasEmail
[1] "mailto:vawebservices@med.va.gov"


$description
[1] "The facilities web service provides VA facility information. The VA facilities locator is a feature that is available across the enterprise, on any webpage, for the Department of Veterans Affairs. It is comprised of data from across the different facilities, and is updated multiple times a day by multiple personnel. This API gives external users the ability to interact with the most up to date information about VA facilities."

$distribution
              @type                                                   accessURL format                      title
1 dcat:Distribution http://www.va.gov/webservices/fandl/documentation/fandl.cfm    API VA Facilities & Leadership

$identifier
[1] "VA-OIT-WSG-01"

$keyword
[1] "Building Information" "Facilities"           "Location"             "VA"
```

If that's not the content you were expecting, it's an issue with the data source. But that's a way to ingest a JSON from a URL to R.